# WordPress loop to include pages content instead of posts

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am developing a one page WordPress theme, there is no need to display any posts, it's just informative page, I was thinking to use static content, but it turned out that I'll need to use dynamic one in order for things like search to work. In "pages" section of WordPres I created a new page which contains all the content I need, I was trying to figure out a loop to include contents of that page, but failed. After doing a research I was only able to find loops used to display content of posts. So is there same loop, but to display contents of page? Also How would I than include those contents in a page e.g.
 `<?php something();?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify the `post_type` inside of the `query_posts()` parameter. For example, if you wanted to output the content of each page, you could do this:

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page'));
while(have_posts()) 
{ 
    echo the_content();
}
```

For reference, you might want to check out the API Reference Docs for [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts).

Comment: Okay, so that loop gets pages instead of posts correct? One last question, how would I then include pages I got from the loop to my page? is it <?php echo $this_page; ?>

Comment: You want to output the content of the page? See the updated answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you, I'll accept your answer once I can ;)

Comment: One quick question, if there are several pages, how can I get a specific one out? e.g. depending on title or something?

Comment: You can access the title using `the_title()`. But you can specify the ID in the params, though.

Comment: yea, I was thinking about id, but the thing is I can't see which id certain page has for some reason, so with the_title(); where in query would I place it? e.g. would I just replace ('post_type') with the_title("First Test"); or is it supposed to go somewhere else?

Comment: You can find the ID in the admin panel. It's a much better solution than retrieving them all and then checking the title.